# Where is Starling City?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

In S2 E13 of the *Arrow*, Felicity pulls up an image of a car that was used in the robbery of snake venom from a zoo.  The car's license plate read "KAZ 547".  She states that the car is a rental and the address for the rental spot was somewhere in the Glades.  Now, a "KAZ" on license plates indicates that the car is from Kansas.  Does this mean that Starling City is in Kansas?  Or is this just another attempt by the writers to keep the true location of the city hidden?  Or, am I missing a really obvious fact about rental cars?

Comment: KAZ on a license plate doesn't indicate anything about what state the plate is from.  Having Kansas plates with KAZ was an in-joke on *Supernatural*, but there's no real significance.

Comment: Even if the rental car is registered in Kansas, that doesn't mean it was rented in Kansas. Rental cars move around a lot.

Comment: The plate number doesn't mean anything about the state.  However, every state in the US issues its own license plates.  They all look different and most of them explicitly mention the state somewhere.  Without a screenshot it's hard to tell, but you might still be able to figure out where that plate is from.  But rentals generally have the "wrong" state's plates anyway, so that might not be useful.

Comment: I suspected that the rental spot in "The Glades" could be a referce to the Everglades in Florida.  But Googling "The Glades" shows that in Arrow "The Glades" is a neighborhood in Star City. http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/The_Glades  and so neither "the Glades" nor the letters on the license plate is a very strong clue to where Star City is.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the license plate you saw is unlikely to indicate anything about Starling City's true location.

> Now, a "KAZ" on license plates indicates that the car is from Kansas. Does this mean that Starling City is in Kansas? Or is this just another attempt by the writers to keep the true location of the city hidden? Or, am I missing a really obvious fact about rental cars?

"KAZ" prefixes do not necessarily indicate Kansas plates, although [Kansas plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_Kansas#1975_to_present) issued between 1994 and 2001 might start with KAZ ("GRS 000 to approximately PAZ 999").  Such a plate would be yellow along the bottom, fading to white in the middle, with light blue along the top, with a sheaf of wheat.

[image: Kansas License Plate 1994-2001]

Because [Arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(TV_series)) is filmed in Vancouver, it's more likely that it was a British Columbia plate.  BC plates tend to be plain white, which helpfully makes them more generic for TV (coincidental I'm sure).  [BC plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_British_Columbia#1970_to_present) issued between 1985 and 2001 might start with KAZ ("LAA 000 to XXX 999").

[image: British Columbia License Plate 1985-2001]

As it turns out, [Supernatural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernatural_(U.S._TV_series)) is also filmed in British Columbia, and both are under the Warner Bros. Television production company.  It would not surprise me at all if the same cars, and the same license plates, ended up being used in both shows, as they're both pulling resources from the limited pool of local prop companies.

[This answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/51385/18130) from Movies.SE points out that cars driving on open roads during a shoot need to use valid local plates - in my personal subjective experience, they must do a lot of regular road shooting in Vancouver, because plates are always my first tip-off that a show is filmed there.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a really obvious fact about rental cars. I recently rented a car in Maryland and it had Connecticut plates. A car rented from a rental place in a given state will not necessarily, or even often, have plates from that same state.